# Will there be any effect on users' bandwidth if I use AngularJS and JQuery at the same time?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bandwidth

I'm a starter in AngularJS, the question is as the title.

Comment: well yeah, they have to download them both, if either isn't already cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular 1.4.4 is 147kb when minified, jQuery 2.1.4 is 84kb when minified. All together this is roughly the equivalent of loading a second (properly optimized) banner image. Leaving out jQuery is the equivalent of leaving an image out of a slideshow. Unless you're target users are in an area with super slow internet this performance impact is negligible.

EDIT: I feel like I should add that if you're starting with angular try not to use the full blown jQuery library. There's a pretty significant shift in the thought processes involved in building web apps with angular vs jQuery. At least initially it's probably best to avoid using it.

Comment: upvote to second not using jquery. Angular can do pretty much anything jquery does anyway.

Comment: I just started using AngularJS with SPA and I found it's really convenient and easy to use, thank you for your answer, I'll keep working.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS comes with a built in lite version of jQuery ([jQLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)). If you can do everything you need to do in your project with jQLite, go for it, if you really really need the full jQuery library, this will mean that users will have to download (at least one, the first time) both jquery and angularjs files, so the answer is Yes, it will affect bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you for your relpy,:)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by Bandwith?
The explorer keeps Scrpits in caché, so when you change or add technology it must be brought from the server, and will be stored in caché.
By the way, i recommend cleaning it to see new changes immediately

Answer (score 0):

As both are used for client side data manipulation. so it will not impact on bandwidth but it will impact page load,response of data handling or loading view.

Suggestion, Avoid using JQuery because it plays with HTML DOM where as in angular it plays with controller-->scope. In a single html page we can also have different  controllers and each controller have their own scope.

At a time use one data handling framework.